# How to create a html irregular table?

Tags: html, html-table

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rhIe.png)
I want to create an HTML irregular table like this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikKWm.png)
but I don't know what's wrong with my code

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test 2</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table border="1" width="500px" height="100px">
            <tr>
                <td>Zoology</td>
                <td rowspan="3">Welcome</td>
                <td>Maths</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Batany</td>
                <td rowspan="3">Physics</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="2">Entomology</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="2">Heading</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Toxicology</td>
                <td>Computer</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Please help!

Comment: From the first image: Are you planning to create a table-based layout? If so, maybe better have a look at [Grids](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Grids)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test 2</title>
        <style>

table, tr, td
{
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}


tr
{
  height: 30px;
}

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table border="1" width="500px" height="100px">
            <tr>
                <td>Zoology</td>
                <td rowspan="3">Welcome</td>
                <td>Maths</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Batany</td>
                <td rowspan="3">Physics</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="2">Entomology</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="2">Heading</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Toxicology</td>
                <td>Computer</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```